# content for bootstrap nav-tab's not showing

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I have a list of locations that I populate from a database. I then use flask and bootstrap to show a [nav-tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) for each iteration in the list.

*I dynamically create a nav-tab for each location in the list when I iterate through it. Which then has dynamic data specific to that tab*

I have been able to get the locations as the nav-tab names. I do not see the content for each tab.

**Q:** What am I doing wrong that causes the content for each tab to not show?

**__init.py__**

```
engine = create_engine('mysql://user:passwd@ip_add/db')
insp = reflection.Inspector.from_engine(engine)
locations = []
for i in insp.get_table_names():
    locations.append(str(i))

@app.route('/dashboard/')
@login_required
def dashboard():
    return render_template("dashboard.html", TOPIC_DICT = TOPIC_DICT, locations=locations)
```

**dashboard.html**

```
{% extends "header.html" %}

{% block body %}
<div>
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    {% for loc in locations %}
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#home" aria-controls="{{ loc }}" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">{{ loc }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
  {% for loc in locations %}
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="{{ loc }}">stuff for {{ loc }}</div>
  {% endfor %}
  </div>

</div>


{% endblock %}
```

**browser view screenshot**

[image]

**browser page source**

When I look at the page source I can see the content 'stuff for PRETORIA', but doesnt show on the page.

```
<div>
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">

    <li role="presentation"><a href="#home" aria-controls="GTSP" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">GTSP</a></li>

    <li role="presentation"><a href="#home" aria-controls="PRETORIA" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">PRETORIA</a></li>

  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">

    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="GTSP">stuff for GTSP</div>

    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="PRETORIA">stuff for PRETORIA</div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You have to add the class `in` to your first tab pane div: `class="tab-pane fade in"`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but no change when I added the `fade in` as you described

Comment: If you add `active` too?

Comment: I published the site `http://95.85.13.29/`    after the register process you get the tabs.

Comment: If you add `class="tab-pane fade in active"` to your first tab pane div the content shows up. The problem is you have to do this in jinja2 `for` loop.

Comment: yes the problem is that its a for loop, so I would need to figure out hot to add a `var = 1` before the tabs are created and then increment the var with 1 to make it False when I `{% if var = 1 add the active to the line %}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that your `a href`s in your nav tabs are linked to incorrect `id`s: each should be linked to the `id` of the corresponding tab content.

```
<li role="presentation"><a href="#GTSP" aria-controls="GTSP" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">GTSP</a></li>

<li role="presentation"><a href="#PRETORIA" aria-controls="PRETORIA" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">PRETORIA</a></li>
```

So you should have in your jinja2 template the `href` set up like so:

```
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    {% for loc in locations %}
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#{{ loc }}" aria-controls="{{ loc }}" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">{{ loc }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

See how is set up the `href` attribute:

```
href="#{{ loc }}"
```